# How to share a self-signed code-signing certificate with other users so they can run my programs?

Tags: windows, certificate, self-signed, code-signing-certificate

I created a self signed code signing certificate in Windows and added it to my Windows application. It is working in my system, but when I copy that exe to some other's computer it is not working.

Can I get a good suggestion for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a self-signed certificate to sign your application, you should install that self-signed certificate on other computers running your software 

On your computer: Export the signing certificate in a *.CER or *.DER file. On the other computers running the application: Install the CER file by double-clicking on it, then clicking on the "install certificate" button. 

The certificate store location must be "Current User" and the store name "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".